# Pycharm multiple anaconda python packages

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda

I have a project created in Pycharm with anaconda3 (python3) as root, and it doesnt recognize certain packages (for example in this case [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) package). When I try to install from terminal it says, Seaborn is already installed in anaconda2 (python2.7).
[image: 1]

How can I manage two different versions of anaconda, because I still have to work with some legacy (python2.7) codes.

My project interpreter is already set to 3.5, whereas the terminal doesn't change accordingly.

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is an ideal case for the usage of virtual environments in python. 
[Virtualenvs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) allow you to maintain versions of python without all of the dependency linking etc that it looks like you are getting into.

With `Anaconda`, this process is even easier as you can use the anaconda's built in [manager](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html) to create a separate python 2 environment with something like the below.

```
conda create --name <yourenvname> python=2.7 anaconda
```

which will install a full blown anaconda environment in 2.7. Doing so will allow you to switch between your python 2 and python 3 without having these managment issues.

For more information see here in Anaconda on using [2or3](https://conda.io/docs/py2or3.html#create-a-python-2-7-environment)